# How to set Authentication and Permission on django URLs for imported views

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-permissions

I want to use django REST framework's inbuilt API documentation. The problem is that I need it to be private with a login and I couldn't manage thus far. I do the following to create my API doc as documented:

```
from rest_framework.documentation import include_docs_urls

API_TITLE = "Cool title"
API_DESCRIPTION = "Badass description"


urlpatterns = [
    path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION)
```

That creates my docs, which is fantastic. But it is accessible by everyone even though I have set my permissions and authentications for all the endpoints to private. I did this like this in my configs:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser',
    )

}
```

But even with this set I can access all site of the docs.

So I am looking for a way to protect my URLs which I imported and thus have no classes or methods at my disposal to protect. (So I can't use any decorators on them). Then I tried using the login required decorator on my URL like so:

`path('docs/', login_required(include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION))),`

but it throws me the following error: `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: registration/login.html`

Is there a way of protecting such URLs?

Help is very much appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: I figured I could pass permission classes as argument to my URL, and indeed Pycharm marks it as an option. So I put:

```
path('docs/', include_docs_urls(title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION, permission_classes= "rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser")),
```

That throws me the error str object not callable. Any ideas on how I could pass my permission classes there maybe?

Comment: figured it out. see my answer

Answer (score 1):

For anyone ever having this problem. It is possible by doing the following:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

    path('api/docs', include_docs_urls(
        title=API_TITLE, description=API_DESCRIPTION, permission_classes=[IsAdminUser]
    ))
```

I wish this inbuilt API documentation tool was documented better. Took me a while to even find out that this exists....